# Java Media Framework video source window

Tags: java, video-capture, jmf

I'm writing a java App thats going to run on windows and uses the JMF, I've got the video capture working but I need to stop the Video Source Window from popping up each time I start the App, this is the first time I've used the JMF however I've looked at the Api and googled but found nothing that talks about the Video Source Window. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you created your window like this:

`ml is your MediaLocator`
`videoPanel is where your adding the video window too`

```
Player player = Manager.createRealizedPlayer(ml);
Component video = player.getVisualComponent();
video.setSize(videoPanel.getSize());
video.setPreferredSize(videoPanel.getPreferredSize());
videoPanel.add(video);
player.start();
```

A simple solution would then to not add the video component to a panel and call `player.stop();`

But without any example of your code, all I can do is speculate.

Hope this helps